# How to type ```mysql``` in Terminal and directly open it?

Tags: mysql, macos, terminal

I installed mysql 5.7.31 on my MacBookAir 2014 with MacOS 11.7.
At the moment I'm able to open it only with:

```
 /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p
```

and adding the password.

I just try with:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

or creating an alias with:

```
alias mysql.start="sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start"
```

It doesn't work, and when i put `mysql` it gives me `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)`.

Before writing this question I red this one: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/176786/how-to-add-mysql-to-path-variable-to-resolve-mysql-command-not-found?newreg=ca86199746ad4e4a82c0a934b7e14d32.

I'm trying to optimise mysql

Answer (score 0):

first try

```
# which mysql
```

to ist the PATH is set correct.

second:

Create a file named .my.cnf in your home directory that looks like this. Make sure the filesystem permissions are set such that only the owning user can read it (0600).

```
[client]
host     = localhost
user     = username
password = thepassword
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
#database = mysql
```

then try **# mysql** again

Comment: I tried  ```# which mysql```                                                                                                
    and  ``` which mysql ```  but both gives me ```zsh : command not found```.